# See or count the amount of emails that a specific Microsoft Exchange mailbox receives

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003

Is there a way to see or count the amount of emails that a specific Microsoft Exchange mailbox receives?

I need to know on average how many emails one specific exchange mailbox receives per month. I can start counting from now, but I was wondering if there is an easy way to get these statistics.

Thanks

Comment: overall? per what time unit? what exchange version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Message Tracking enabled then you can track the messages a mailbox (user) recieves in a given time period.

Comment: With a Google search on Message Tracking Exchange 2003 I was able to find the information I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the exchange.log folder. There should be a log per day ex 20100604.log . You can copy this log and analyse it in excel.

Please check this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246965 to find out what the fields represent.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 - Message tracking FTW. I gave it to you rather than joeqwerty because you included a link to the description of the tracking log files.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but just in case anyone is still looking for a solution to this problem, you can use the [Microsoft Exchange Server Profile Analyzer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16088).

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.